# How to optimize the DOM inserting loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, optimization

For example : I want to insert many `tr` in a table like this

```
var tbody = $('#tbody') 
  // Suppose the articlelist is the data from ajax 
    while (articlelist.length > 0) {
        var article = articlelist.shift(),

        var tr = $(' <tr>'
           +' <td>'+article.id+'</td>'
            +'<td>' + article.channelid +'</td>'
           + '<td>'+article.comment+'</td>'
           +'<td>'+article.last_edit_time+'</td><td>'

         )
        tbody.append(tr)
    }
```

To avoid create the `<tr>...</tr>` in loop .Is it possible to use a class to generate the tr content ？

Comment: @PranavCBalan is it clone() could insert custom data, like ID

Comment: `$('.your-tr-class').clone().html('td html code here')`

Comment: @snookieordie excellent

Comment: if you are concerned by performances, you could try one of the virtual DOM libraries, like React, Riot.js and so on

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop to concatenate all the strings, then append this lengthy string all at once. This would help with performance for many `tr`s

```
var tbody = $('#tbody') 
var rows = ''
while (articlelist.length > 0) {
    var article = articlelist.shift(),

    rows += '<tr><td>'+article.id+'</td>'
       +'<td>' + article.channelid +'</td>'
       + '<td>'+article.comment+'</td>'
       +'<td>'+article.last_edit_time+'</td><tr>';
}  
tbody.append(rows)
```

Comment: replace this `tbody.append(tr)` with `tbody.append(rows)`

Answer (score 2):

An optimized version:

```
var tbody = $('#tbody'),        
    htmlStr = "";

for (var i = 0, len = articlelist.length; i < len; i++) {  // avoid accessing 'length' property on each iteration
     htmlStr += '<tr><td>' + articlelist[i].id + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + articlelist[i].channelid + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + articlelist[i].comment + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + articlelist[i].last_edit_time + '</td><td><tr>';        
}
tbody.append(htmlStr); // parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

add a function like this to do this for you.

```
while (articlelist.length > 0) {
    make_content(article);
}

function make_content(article) {
     var tbody = $('#tbody');
     var tr = $(' <tr>'
       +' <td>'+article.id+'</td>'
        +'<td>' + article.channelid +'</td>'
       + '<td>'+article.comment+'</td>'
       +'<td>'+article.last_edit_time+'</td><td>'

     )
    tbody.append(tr)
}
```